# Capybara click_link doesn't take parameters after question mark

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

Capybara standard step with my debugger point:

```
When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
  debugger
  click_link(link)
end
```

In debugger console I look at `page.body` and see this link:

```
<a href=\"/movies/find_all_by_director/George%20Lucas?movie_id=1\">Find Movies With Same Director</a>
```

But Cucumber test gives me an error:

```
When I follow "Find Movies With Same Director"
  No route matches [GET] "/movies/find_all_by_director/George%20Lucas" (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

Where is my `movie_id` parameter?

UPDATE: There may be a mistake. `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rottenpotatoes::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :movies
  get 'movies/find_all_by_director/:director?movie_id=:movie_id' => 'movies#find_all_by_director', :as => 'find_all_by_director'
end
```

Comment: If you fix the missing route it may show up in the parameters.

Comment: I fix route with that: `get 'movies/find_all_by_director/:director' => 'movies#find_all_by_director', :as => 'find_all_by_director'`, pass "follow" test and get an error with "should be on" test: `expected: "/movies/find_all_by_director/George%20Lucas?movie_id=1" got: "/movies/find_all_by_director/George%20Lucas"`

Comment: I pass "should be on" test with fixing standard `web_steps.rb`. It seems like error was in route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click this link in a browser does it come up with an routing error as well?

I don't think it's to do with capybara (click_link definitely does honor query params). It's just that Rails is answering that there's no route -- the query params don't generally influence routing so they are irrelevant to it.

see also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string but note it might be possible for routing to be adjusted by [segment constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints):

Comment: I can't click this link in a browser because I have no appropriate data in DB - Cucumber generates it for itself in "Background" section of test suite.